# Re-Sign In with Apple to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

I've got an iOS app setup with Sign In with Apple to Firebase. Tho every re-launch of the app, I need to re-auth with Face ID. This can quickly get annoying, especially in development, where I re-launch the app hundres of times a day.

I followed this tutorial: [Firebase - Sign In with Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple)

```
let appleIDCredential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential = ...
let appleIDUser: String = appleIDCredential.user
let appleIDToken: String = String(data: appleIDCredential.identityToken, encoding: .utf8)
let credential: OAuthCredential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: magicNonce)
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in /* done */ }
```

I got the [credentials](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential) the first time, is there a way to re-use them?

Comment: Why are you re-authenticating every time you launch the app? Is this a requirement for your app? Once you login with `Auth.auth().signIn(with:)`, Firebase stores your account automatically and keeps it until you explicitly call `Auth.auth().signOut()`, even across app restarts.

Comment: ah, I did not know that, nice, thanks!

Comment: No problem! I think you should close this question if you think you've got the answer you were looking for.